# ¿Cómo puedo recargar un textarea con jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estoy utilizando **jquery** para recargar un `textarea`, pero se quita el texto. El párrafo lo tengo en una base de datos **mysql** y mediante un `echo` muestro el texto.

```
setInterval(function(){
    $("#notes_desc").load(" index.php"); 
},5000);
```

HTML:

```
<textarea name="parrafo" id="notes_desc" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"><?php echo $row['parrafo']; ?></textarea>
```

Js donde envío el post:

```
function autoSave()
    {
        var notes_desc = document.getElementById('notes_desc').value;
        var notes_id = document.getElementById('notes_id').value;
        if(notes_desc!='')
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:'text.php',
                method:"post",
                data:{notes_desc : notes_desc,notes_id:notes_id},
                success:function(response)
                {
                    if(response!='')
                    {
                    document.getElementById('notes_id').value=response; 
                    }
                    document.getElementById('autoSaveText').innerHTML="Cambios guardados. :)";
                
                }
            });
        }
    }
    setInterval(function(){
        autoSave();
    },2000);

        setInterval(function(){
                        document.getElementById('autoSaveText').innerHTML="";
                    },2000);
```

En el archivo `text.php` está la consulta a la BD.

`Notes_id` es el `id` de la fila en la BD, lo pongo para que en la consulta vaya a la fila especifica. Lo que he hecho hasta ahora bien es que cada *x* segundos se haga un `update` a la BD sin reiniciar la página.

Básicamente quiero que 2 o más usuarios puedan modificar el `textarea` de manera simultánea.

El código que estoy usando está sacado de este video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7ba1kVrZRc&t=1s , ya que no soy muy experimentado en `js` ni en `jquery`.

**EDIT:** Ya lo testee cambiando el .load por .val, pero no pasa nada.

Comment: El método `jQuery.load()` es para cargar nuevo contenido HTML en un elemento que no sea campo de formulario. En todo caso, debes ejecutar una [petición AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) y asignar el valor con el método adecuado: [jQuery.val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: Por cierto, no dupliques preguntas, porque complica que recibas una respuesta. Te recomiendo eliminar [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/516134/54039) porque es sobre lo mismo, pero está incompleta.